# Django Google Suspicious Operation

Tags: django

I'm new to Django, and keep getting the same error emailed to me. It's regarding the allowed hosts (using Django 1.5). Why does it see Google as Suspicious? Should I allow Google, will it stop my site from being indexed?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/newrelic-1.11.0.55/newrelic/api/object_wrapper.py", line 216, in __call__
    self._nr_instance, args, kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/newrelic-1.11.0.55/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 57, in process_request
    host = request.get_host()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/request.py", line 72, in get_host
    "Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): %s" % host)

SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): www.google.com


<WSGIRequest
path:/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/srv/project/sms',
'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html',
'HTTP_HOST': 'www.google.com',
'HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION': 'close',
'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
'PATH_INFO': u'/',
'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/srv/project/sms/apache/django.wsgi/',
'QUERY_STRING': '',
'REMOTE_ADDR': '183.91.14.60',
'REMOTE_PORT': '55739',
'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
'REQUEST_URI': 'http://www.google.com/',
'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/srv/project/sms/apache/django.wsgi',
'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
'SERVER_ADDR': '10.229.37.116',
'SERVER_ADMIN': '[no address given]',
'SERVER_NAME': 'www.google.com',
'SERVER_PORT': '80',
'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
'SERVER_SIGNATURE': '<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at www.google.com Port 80</address>\n',
'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)',
'mod_wsgi.application_group': 'www.domain.com|',
'mod_wsgi.callable_object': 'application',
'mod_wsgi.handler_script': '',
'mod_wsgi.input_chunked': '0',
'mod_wsgi.listener_host': '',
'mod_wsgi.listener_port': '80',
'mod_wsgi.process_group': 'domain.com',
'mod_wsgi.request_handler': 'wsgi-script',
'mod_wsgi.script_reloading': '1',
'mod_wsgi.version': (3, 3),
'wsgi.errors': <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x7f348e39a6f0>,
'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0x7f348e3f7d50>,
'wsgi.input': <newrelic.api.web_transaction.WSGIInputWrapper object at 0x7f348de819d0>,
'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
'wsgi.multithread': True,
'wsgi.run_once': False,
'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
'wsgi.version': (1, 1)}>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone from 183.91.14.60 (REMOTE_ADDR) is connecting to your server and asking for Google's home page (REQUEST_URI); as you are not hosting Google this is indeed suspicious. This is not related to the Google index bot.

I have also seen this request on my server (but not this error message) from this IP address.  My guess is someone is scanning servers looking for open proxies.

I would not add www.google.com to any allowed host list.

If you are receiving a lot of these from the same REMOTE_ADDR I would consider adding that IP address to /etc/hosts.deny or to a block list on your firewall. How to do this will depend on your set up and is, I suspect, beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

"Make sure that the host name you are passing to your application server (probably via nginx) doesn't have an _ in it or Django will not validate the hostname in production"

from: http://timmyomahony.com/blog/2013/04/24/suspiciousoperation-invalid-http_host-header-django/

Comment: No, I think is all working as it should. the question is why is Google triggering this and should I add Google to the allowed hosts?